# html form not displaying values

Tags: php, forms

Scenario:
I have this simple HTML 5 Form inside the PHP tag.

```
<?php
echo '
    <form method="post" action="index.php">    
    <input type="email" name="email value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
    <input type="password" name="password">  
    <button type="submit" name="signin">Sign in</button> 
    </form>

';


?>
```

The form displays correctly but I can not get the value of $email, it just displays as raw text.

So, how to echo a php variable from a form inside a PHP tag.

FINAL CODE

```
<?php
   echo '<form method="post" action="index.php" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
           <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control1" value="' . $email . '">
           <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
           <button type="submit" name="signin">Sign in</button>
         </form>'; 
?>
```

Comment: Put a space between name and value attribute, and you echo into an echo. I think that will not work, just put the html string after your php closing tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape out from the string with `'` and concatenate with `.` that way you can use php variables into an string

```
<?php
    echo '
        <form method="post" action="index.php">    
        <input type="email" name="email "value="' . $email .'">   
        <input type="password" name="password">  
        <button type="submit" name="signin">Sign in</button> 
        </form>
    ';
?>
```

Or like  said in the comment, place the html code after your php closing tag

```
<?php
    // Do some code
    ?>
  <form method="post" action="index.php">    
     <input type="email" name="email "value="<?= $email; ?>">   
     <input type="password" name="password">  
     <button type="submit" name="signin">Sign in</button> 
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Closing the Form tag:

```
<?php
echo '
    <form method="post" action="index.php">    
    <input type="email" name="email"value="<?php echo $email; ?>">   
    <input type="password" name="password">  
    <button type="submit" name="signin">Sign in</button>
    </form>
';


?>
```

Comment: Nice, but still does not recognise the   php echo $email  as a value

Comment: I have not used PHP in a while and just noticed a form tag missing so thought I would at least offer that assistance. I seem to recall using $_POST arrays with the data going into there. Not sure if that helps, but might be something worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access your variables for an echo statement you have to use double quotes. and you can put single quotes inside double quotes.

```php
$email = "example@gmail.com";
echo "
    <form method='post' action='index.php'>    
        <input type='email' name='email' value='$email'>
    </form>
";
```

or even using [Heredoc](https://www.php.net/heredoc)

```php
$email = "example@gmail.com";
echo <<<HTML
    <form method="post" action="index.php">    
        <input type="email" name="email" value="$email">   
        <input type="password" name="password">  
        <button type="submit" name="signin">Sign in</button> 
    </form>
HTML;
```